# Python searching 2d arrays and returning if found and index found at

Tags: python

I have a 2d array which may or may not contain data. First I want to search for the index that contains specific data and if true then update the data in the array.

So far I have managed to search the array and return a true or false statement if the index is found. But I also need to return the index value so I can then modify and update the data in the array.

```
from itertools import chain
self.asset= [[]]

def findIn2dArray(self, arr, value):
    return value in chain.from_iterable(arr)

if self.findIn2dArray(self.asset, element.get("asset")):
     print("found updating")
     self.asset[???, 1] = new updated value
```

I know which columns I will need to change but I don't know the index location of the data, hope that makes sense. It would be good if the findIn2dArray function would also return the index number, thanks!

Comment: `chain.from_iterable` flattens it into 1 dimension, so you can't get the original indexes.

Comment: Side comment: it doesn't look like you've set up a class, so you shouldn't be using the `self` parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't flatten the 2d list. Use nested loops with `enumerate()` so you can get the indexes.

```
def find_in_2d(lists, value):
    for i, l in enumerate(lists):
        for j, item in enumerate(l):
            if item == value:
                return i, j
    return None, None

i, j = find_in_2d(assets, element.get("asset")
if i is not None:
    print("found updating")
    asset[i][j] = new_value
```